# generate random integer elements in an array

Tags: matlab, random

How can I generate particular number of random numbers in MATLAB and store it in an array?

I used `rand()`, but I got decimal values. How can I get integers?

Comment: For integers with _uniform_ distribution, see `randi`. Or multiply `rand` times the maximum desired number and then apply `ceil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `randi()` instead of `rand()` but you will have to specify the range, for example:

```
randi([5, 120])
```

As commented by Luis Mendo, it will give you **uniformly distributed** pseudorandom numbers.

To save them in an array:

```
i = 10000;             % max value
myarray = zeros(1, i); % creating array
for K = 1:i
   myarray(K) = randi([5, 120]);
end
```

or even shorter:

```
randi([5, 120], 1, 10000)
```

Comment: Should be better now :)

Comment: One last comment: why not vectorize? `myarray = randi([5, 120], 1, 10000)`. No need for a loop

Comment: @LuisMendo +1 and because I'm not used to this notation :D But thanks for the input !!

Comment: @LuisMendo Very nice of you to help achedeuzot and not just make your own answer. Always gracious!